# Trying to combine columns based on data from multiple rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am not too bad with VBA but have been struggling to find a solution for this

I have a table with data in Columns A-L - I am trying to merge the rows which are the same from A-K, but where L is different I would like them in the same cell

Example data below

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 8981 | 1/12/2020 | 77777 | Site Name 1 | 123 Lane |  | London | UK | SW14 | Chrome | Manufacturer |
| ABC123 | 8981 | 1/12/2020 | 77777 | Site Name 1 | 123 Lane |  | London | UK | SW14 | Edge | Developer |
| ABC123 | 8981 | 1/12/2020 | 77777 | Site Name 1 | 123 Lane |  | London | UK | SW14 | Chrome | Importer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | IE | Importer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | Safari | Developer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | Safari | Developer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | Safari | Importer |
| XXX345 | 9999 | 25/10/2023 | 55555 | Site Name 3 | 123 Road |  | Liverpool | UK | LI12 | Edge | Importer |

Trying to achieve this

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 8981 | 1/12/2020 | 77777 | Site Name 1 | 123 Lane |  | London | UK | SW14 | Chrome | Manufacturer, Importer |
| ABC123 | 8981 | 1/12/2020 | 77777 | Site Name 1 | 123 Lane |  | London | UK | SW14 | Edge | Developer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | IE | Importer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | Safari | Developer, Importer |
| XXX345 | 9999 | 25/10/2023 | 55555 | Site Name 3 | 123 Road |  | Liverpool | UK | LI12 | Edge | Importer |

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

After that the next step I want to do is this

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 8981 | 1/12/2020 | 77777 | Site Name 1 | 123 Lane |  | London | UK | SW14 | Chrome | Manufacturer, Importer | Edge | Developer |
| BGC123 | 1234 | 1/1/2019 | 22222 | Site Name 2 | 123 Street |  | Manchester | UK | CH13 | IE | Importer | Safari | Developer, Importer |
| XXX345 | 9999 | 25/10/2023 | 55555 | Site Name 3 | 123 Road |  | Liverpool | UK | LI12 | Edge | Importer |  |  |

But will try to figure this out once the first part is done, unless anyone thinks it can be done at the same time!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA version:

```
Sub Tester()
    Const N_KEY_COLS = 10 'Columns which identify a unique 
                          '  row in output data
    Dim dict As Object, rw As Range, k As String, cOut As Range, brws, role, c As Range, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set cOut = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("N2") 'first output cell
    
    Set rw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2").Resize(1, N_KEY_COLS) 'first address
    Do While Application.CountA(rw) > 0
        k = RowKey(rw) 'get a "key" for the address info
        If Not dict.Exists(k) Then
            cOut.Offset(dict.count).Resize(1, N_KEY_COLS).Value = rw.Value
            dict.Add k, dict.count
        End If
        brws = rw.Cells(N_KEY_COLS).Offset(0, 1).Value
        role = rw.Cells(N_KEY_COLS).Offset(0, 2).Value
        Set c = cOut.Offset(dict(k), N_KEY_COLS)
        Do
            v = c.Value
            If v = brws Or Len(v) = 0 Then 'adding content?
                If Len(v) = 0 Then c.Value = brws
                AddIfNewValue c.Offset(0, 1), role
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set c = c.Offset(0, 2)
        Loop
        
        Set rw = rw.Offset(1) 'next input row
    Loop
End Sub

'Join all values in row range `rw` with "~~" to create a "key"
Function RowKey(rw As Range)
    RowKey = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rw.Value)), "~~")
End Function

'Add value `vNew` to range `c` if not already present
'  Values in c are separated by vbLf
Sub AddIfNewValue(c As Range, vNew)
    Dim v, arr, el
    v = c.Value
    If Len(v) = 0 Then
        c.Value = vNew
    Else
        arr = Split(v, vbLf)
        For Each el In arr
            If el = vNew Then Exit Sub 'nothing to add
        Next
        c.Value = v & vbLf & vNew
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you, on initial testing it works as expected! just changed it slightly to put the output onto a new sheet but looks like what I am after. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need VBA for this - if you have Excel 365 try this formula:

```vb
=LET(
    data, A2:L9,
    t, TAKE(data, , -1),
    c, BYROW(DROP(data, , -1), LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN("|", FALSE, r))),
    x, DROP(REDUCE("", c, LAMBDA(r, v, VSTACK(r, TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, UNIQUE(FILTER(t, c = v, "")))))), 1),
    result1, UNIQUE(HSTACK(DROP(data, , -1), x)),
    cc, BYROW(DROP(result1, , -2), LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN("|", FALSE, r))),
    xx, IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("", cc, LAMBDA(r, v, VSTACK(r, TOROW(FILTER(TAKE(result1, , -2), cc = v))))), 1), ""),
    UNIQUE(HSTACK(DROP(result1, , -2), xx))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you, this is great, I have other VBA formaulas in this workbook as I do other bits of manipulation too, but I could still use this and add the formula into the script. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)` and what I see it will be easier & simpler to achieve using the said tool.

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps: (Read the steps annotations to follow)

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table_ONE`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    //Step 1 Uploaded Data into Power Query
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_ONE"]}[Content],

    //Step 2 ChangedDataType
    ChangedDataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"A", type text}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", type date}, {"D", Int64.Type}, {"E", type text}, {"F", type text}, {"G", type any}, {"H", type text}, {"I", type text}, {"J", type text}, {"K", type text}, {"L", type text}}),

    //Step 3 Removed Duplicates
    DistinctRecords = Table.Distinct(ChangedDataType),

    //Step 4 GroupedBy A To K Columns
    GroupByBrowsers = Table.Group(DistinctRecords, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"}, {{"All", each Text.Combine([L],","), type nullable text}}),

    //Step 5 Merged Columns K & All(returned from step 4)
    MergedColumnsK_All = Table.CombineColumns(GroupByBrowsers,{"K", "All"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),

    //Step 6 GroupBy A To J Columns
    GroupByAtoJ = Table.Group(MergedColumnsK_All, {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"}, {{"Header", each Text.Combine([Merged],"|"), type text}}),

    //Step 7 Split By Delimiters
    SplitByDelimiters = Table.SplitColumn(GroupByAtoJ, "Header", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Header.1", "Header.2", "Header.3", "Header.4"})
in
    SplitByDelimiters
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Here is an `MS365 Beta Version Excel Formula` approach:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _DistinctRecords, UNIQUE(Table_ONE),
     _GroupOne, GROUPBY(DROP(_DistinctRecords,,-1),TAKE(_DistinctRecords,,-1),ARRAYTOTEXT,,0),
     _GroupTwo, GROUPBY(DROP(_GroupOne,,-2),INDEX(_GroupOne,,11)&"|"&INDEX(_GroupOne,,12)&"|",CONCAT,,0),
     _UniqueRecords, UNIQUE(DROP(_GroupTwo,,-1)),
     _RecordsToSplit, TAKE(_GroupTwo,,-1),
     _SplitInstances, SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(_RecordsToSplit)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_RecordsToSplit,"|",)))),
     _Output, IFERROR(HSTACK(_UniqueRecords,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&_RecordsToSplit,"|",_SplitInstances),"|")),""),
     _Output)
```

---

**Note:** One downside/stumbling block to the above or these formulas which uses the `TEXTJOIN()` functions, and that is *an important caveat to remember, it may return the `#VALUE!` error if the resulting string exceeds `32767` **characters (cell limit)**. However, if its less data and within the limits then one can use it successfully.* Therefore personally, I would opt-in for a more flexible method like `POWER-QUERY`.

---

Comment: Thank you, I have existing Macros within this code so thats why opted for VBA, but this is a good approach, and would like to look into Power Queries more. Thanks for your help